# Need mySql query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have *n* number of users with different **articleId**.
If I pass the **articleId**, I want to get the results like how many different users viewed that article.

`Table` 1:

```
recId   userId   articleId    
-----   ------    --------
100      1001      1   
103      178       2   
106      475       3   
107      327       4   
108      567       5   
109      568       6
```

`Table` 2:

```
userId     jobtitle        articleId
-----       ------          --------  
  327       Engineer          4
  178       Professor         4
  475       Doctors           4
  327       Engineer          5
  568       Student           6
  475       Doctors           4
  475       Doctors           8
```

If I pass the  **articleId** as  **4**, It should return the details like how many times that particular article viewed by different users like:

```
jobtitle   total
-----      ------    
Doctors     2
Engineer    1
Professor   1
```

if i pass **articleid** as **6**, result will be like this:

```
jobtitle   total
-----      ------    
Student      1
```

How to write this mysql script?

Comment: I don't understand your database structure. Why don't you use proper table names instead of Table1 / Table2? I am assuming Table1 stores the fact that a particular user read an article, and I assume Table2  stores all your users, but can't be sure as you don't give any hint. If my assumption is correct, what is articleid doing in Table2? 

Need more information.

Comment: Your profession names should be stored in a separate table and you should use a foreign key.

Comment: HI roland,  I am not given table name as Table1 & Table 2. just for Testing example i have mentioned like that.Actually, this is not a original data. just i want to make sure about my result, i have made draft data. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT jobtitle, COUNT(*) as count
FROM Table2
WHERE articleId = 4
GROUP BY jobtitle
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select jobtitle, count(articleid)
from table2 
where articleid = YOUR_ARTICLE_ID
group by jobtitle
```